# How to stop preloading image of javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to build a image gallery for mobile.

I have stored image into an array(photos array).

It working fine except that it is preloading all images of array. I dont want to preload image, start loading image only after function forward or backward is called.

I have try these code into UC browse & google chrome. In UC browser its not preloading the image but in chrome it does.

View Code

#### Javascript

```
<script>
    function setImage(imageURL){
       document.getElementById('myimage').style.display='none';
       document.getElementById('limg').style.display='block';
       document.images.myimage.src=imageURL; setTimeout('doWhileLoading()',100);
    }
    function doWhileLoading(){
        if(document.images.myimage.complete){
            document.getElementById('myimage').style.display='block';
            document.getElementById('limg').style.display='none';
        } else{
            setTimeout('doWhileLoading()',100);
        }
    }
    function forward(){
        if(which<photos.length-1){
           which++;
           setImage(photos[which]);
        }
    }
    function backward(){
        if(which>1){
            which--;
            setImage(photos[which]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<div id='load'>
    <img src='files/971220/load1.gif'id='limg'><img src='mk1.jpg'name='myimage'id='myimage'>
</div>
<a href='#'onclick='backward();return false'>prev</a>
<a href='#'onclick='forward();return false'>next</a>
```

Comment: please insert code in the question, external sources are subject to be moved, deleted, making the question irrelevant for further reading

Comment: @Kaiido right, I move code from external link to question.

Comment: I would suggest you start all over again. Where is `which` defined. Why is there a setTimeout triggered to change the images 10 times a second when user clicks forward or backward? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: And you're not even defining any array, `document.images` is an HTML collection of `img` into the document;  because your populating your `img` elements, then of course they get loaded.

Comment: 'Which' value like is a interger value which i am taking from url using php GET

Comment: Photos array is just like that
var photos=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{photos[i]='files/971220/mk'+i+'.jpg';}

Comment: Then your array is not an array of images but an array of strings (urls). There is no reason that the browser preloads any images before you set those urls to the src of your image element, as it doesn't know it is referring to actual images. How do you know it is preloading them?

Comment: Please see here some type code is use 
http://wallpapers.wapego.net/main.php?f=3259946
actually i am trying to make image gallery which change image by prev and next function and show a loading image when image is loading

Comment: If after page load i off my
data connection and after it if i click on prev and next then
still next & prev image is
shown without data conn. without preloading it is impossible to load remaining images of array